# What kind of Control is this? C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a control in winforms that looks like this?

[image]

I'm just wondering how is this made..
Thanks.

Comment: PropertyGrid is pretty close.

Comment: yes, is PropertyGrid only used for other controls?

Comment: No, it can display any object.  Although you may need a TypeConverter to make it look good.

Comment: ok, I thought it was just for winform controls. Thanks for the info.

Comment: It looks more than a TreeListView in the Left Side ,and a ListBox in the Right Side .And the background contains lines texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/treelistview.aspx when I had the need of such control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for controls with these names 'TreeList', 'TreeListView'

Answer (score 0):

There is a control with the name **PropertyGrid**. I think it will serve all your requirements.